# Remove duplicate in SQL with specfic column

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

My requirement is to remove duplicate in sql query with specific column (i.e. similar to remove duplicate option in MS Excel.)

Eg: my query o/p is with 8 column but duplicate to be removed with 3 columns. With the following 8 column

```
date,name, dept_name,city,phne_no,country,gender,age
```

i need to remove duplicate w.r.t

```
name, city, phne_no
```

Is this possible in sql? Please note that i do not have access to delete data in table hence i can only extract. Kindly help me out.

Comment: if you have two rows with the same `name`, `city`, and `phne_no`, which row do you keep?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you can `delete` a row if another row with the same name, city, and phne_no `EXISTS`, but with a newer date:

```
   delete from tablename t1 where exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                                           where t1.name = t2.name
                                             and t1.city = t2.city
                                             and t1.phne_no = t2.phne_no
                                             and t2.date > t1.date)
```

**Edit:**
If you just want to `select` the newer rows, use `NOT EXISTS` to find rows without any newer "duplicates":

```
select *
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t1.name = t2.name
                    and t1.city = t2.city
                    and t1.phne_no = t2.phne_no
                    and t2.date > t1.date)
```

Comment: I can only extract data through a query and i dont have access to delete data